# Need IP to connect custom domain name on Zeit

Tags: deployment, dns, next.js, vercel

I need some help please. I am new to Now and Zeit. I have created a website with Next JS and deployed it properly on Zeit. I am trying to connect my custom domain to it (my client got it on arsys.es). However on arsys.es, if I want to change the nameservers, I need an IP for each of them and Zeit doens't provide me with one. I have tried as well using DNS entry and a CNAME using the data Zeit gives me for ALIAS but still not working. I contacted arsys.es and they told me on top of the CNAME I would need a A entry with an IP. Once again I can't get an IP from Zeit.
I have googled it a lot and can't find a solution.
Can anyone help at all please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a break-down of options that you have:

**UPDATE:** There is an update in the "A record" option.

### 1. Use NameServers

When you insert a new production domain, Now will generate a set of NameServers for your domain.

#### Pros:

- Doing any operation with Now will be very easy, since ZEIT is handling all DNS for you automatically.
- You can insert DNS records using a CLI tool.
- Apex domain can be used.

#### Cons:

- There is no UI to manage DNS.
- Propagation can take a while.

### 2. Use CNAME/ANAME/ALIAS:

#### Pros:

- Only a subdomain will be available to ZEIT Now.
- Your registrar/DNS provider will still control the DNS configuration.

#### Cons:

- You need to add a CNAME for every subdomain that you want to use.
- Apex domain can become problematic. Even when using ALIAS/ANAME, CDN performance can be affected.

### 3. CF Proxy:

#### Pros:

- You can manage any records through Cloudflare DNS UI.
- Cloudflare features.

#### Cons:

- Advanced DNS knowledge may be required.
- Apex domain can become problematic. Even when using ALIAS/ANAME, CDN performance can be affected.
- CDN performance will be affected if the CF proxy is enabled.
- CF CDN can interfere with ZEIT CDN.

### 4. A record:

#### Pros:

- Easy to setup.

#### Cons:

UPDATE: This is no longer true. Read the edit below. A records are now **recommended**.

- CDN will be disabled. Not a problem if you are serving a single region.
- The site can go down if ZEIT Now purges the IP that you are using. I highly recommend that you use the solutions above.

UPDATE: Since the rebrand, Vercel launched a new edge network. All users can use "76.76.21.21" and it is a permanent IP that belongs to the company. [Blog link](https://vercel.com/blog/new-edge-dev-infrastructure)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you point your DNS entries to Zeit's nameservers, Zeit doesn't do `A` records. It does `ANAME` records and `CNAME` records. Most DNS providers don't offer `ANAME` records, so you're stuck with a `CNAME`. The apex domain, however, cannot be a `CNAME`. So what you need to do is setup a `CNAME` for `www.yourdomain.com` and then point your apex A record to a domain forwarding service, which will forward any request for `yourdomain.com` to `www.yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the lastest vercel feature, which is to use A record pointing to the dedicated IP of 76.76.21.21, however in route 53, remember to use "blank" instead of the "@" when setting up.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records  see explanation here